# pyarrow - Write binary file in arrow format

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

How do I write a file `./my-data.arrow` using the arrow binary format?

Note I don't want a Parquet file.

```
import pyarrow as pa

data = [('A', 1), ('B', 2)]
schema = pa.schema([
    ('name', pa.string()),
    ('id', pa.int64())
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Arrow IPC format, for historic reasons also known as "Feather": [docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/feather.html) [name faq](https://arrow.apache.org/faq/#what-about-the-feather-file-format)

You can write either a pandas.DataFrame or pyarrow.Table like this:

```
import pyarrow.feather as feather
feather.write_feather(df, '/path/to/file')
```